# get the height of a div based on other divs heights

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, height

here's a simple html sample:

```
<div id="column-5" style="height:300px;width:200px;background:red">
<div class="httwitter-thread-navigation" style="height:223px;width:100%;background:pink">
    <div class="mydiv" style="width:auto;background:yellow;"></div>
</div>
```

what i want to achieve is giving the height to .mydiv based on the following operation:
.mydiv's height should be "#column-5's height" - ".httwitter-thread-navigation's height - 40px"

which translates in this case in

300 - 223 - 40 = 37px

how do i get the 37px height with javascript?

consider that the heights of column-5 or the other one may not be specified in the css, so the javascript should detect it's innerHeights (including margins and paddings)

thank you so much

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/omegaiori/hafn5/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> .mydiv's height should be "#column-5's height" -
>   ".httwitter-thread-navigation's height - 40px"

that pretty much sums it up ?

```
$('.mydiv').height(function() {
    return $('#column-5').height() - $('.httwitter-thread-navigation').height() - 40;
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/hafn5/2/)

jQuery has both [**outerHeight**](http://api.jquery.com/outerheight/) and [**innerHeight**](http://api.jquery.com/innerheight/) as well, depending on what you need. Read the docs.

Comment: @omegaiori - if innerHeight is what you're after, yes it is. Both your fiddle and the one in the answer sets the height to 37px

Answer (score 1):

here you go:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.mydiv').css('height', ($('#column-5').height() - $('.httwitter-thread-navigation').height() - 40);

});
```